# What does '\' mean in the context of this perl script

Tags: perl

I need to explain the  why the output of this perl code is wrong but I don't understand what '\' means in perl.
**This is School Work**

```
#!/user/bin/perl
$x=5;
$y=\$x;
print "$x , $y, $$y \n";
$x=6;
print "$x , $y, $$y \n";
$y=4;
print "$x , $y, $$y\n";
```

also this is the, output it gives.

```
5 , SCALAR(0x8daaa0), 5 
6 , SCALAR(0x8daaa0), 6 
6 , 4,
```

Comment: `SCALAR(0x8daaa0)` is how a reference to another variable looks like in perl when printed. The word will describe the type of reference (HASH, ARRAY, SCALAR..).

Comment: FYI, if an answer is "correct" please mark it so by clicking the check mark next to it

Comment: Always use `use strict; use warnings;`!

Comment: Operators are documented in [perlop](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html). Your Perl version's available via command `perldoc perlop`.

Answer (score 6):

`\` is reference operator. `$y` now holds a reference to `$x`. So `$$y` is `$x`.

You can refer to [perldoc perlreftut](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlreftut.html) for more information.

Answer (score 3):

Look into [perldoc perlref](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlref.html) that explains references.

Answer (score 1):

The `\` takes a reference to the variable following it.

To show [warnings](http://p3rl.org/lexwarn), add:

```
use warnings;
```

Comment: thank you that does tell me whats wrong now I just need to figure out how to fix it!